# How relevant is XSL

Tags: xml, ajax, xslt

Is there a better way to format data uniformly than to store data as an XML in a data base, and asynchronously retrieve it with an XSL document to format and display it using ajax requests?

I haven't really had a need to use XSL for a while now, and recently I was working on a project where I thought that it would be useful. I went looking for an Aptana Studio plug-in that might let me cheat by giving me code completion suggestions. While looking, I found a couple forums where comments were made that there aren't many people using XSL any more, and that got me thinking: is this a relevant technology anymore?

Comment: All technology has some use somewhere. I don't think this is relevant question for SO.

Comment: What would be a more appropriate forum? Besides in the about link for SO, the site is described as "a programming Q & A site". I thought I was at least in the ballpark with relevancy.

Comment: No, they don't want opinionated discussion threads on this forum, mainly because it isn't a forum! Your question will be closed soon.

Comment: This site is littered with opinionated questions. In fact, just about any question that asks how to accomplish any programming task could be an opinion, as there could be many ways to accomplish any given task. And for the record, a forum can be defined as "an assembly, meeting place, television program, etc., for the discussion of questions of public interest."

Comment: Can you reword the question so that it reads 'Would XSL solve {some specific problem} in my project?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People always make comments such as XSLT isn't relevant any more, which translates as 'I have no need for XSLT'. There are currently 8,371 questions on SO tagged with XSLT, so yes, that seems pretty relevant.

My previous job was principally as an XSLT stylesheet designer, and I did it for 8 years (I also did java, C++ and C#) and the stuff I did there which was html formatting for display, I would have had difficulty doing using other methods. Obviously it wouldn't have been impossible, but it was the best tool for the job. I also did XSLT-FO there, which again would have been harder to to in another way, the only way I could think of would have been css3, which would have also needed XSLT.

So yes, it was very relevant to me. If you don't need it, it is not relevant to you. It is a matter of perspective like so many things